# Understanding Walters' proof for existence and uniqueness of $g$-measures.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $(X,T)$ be a one-sided topologically mixing subshift of finite type, and $g:X\to \mathbb R$ be a strictly positive, continuous function, satisfying 
$$\sum_{y\in T^{-1}x}g(y)=1,\quad\forall x\in X.$$
In other words $g$ is what is commonly known as a $g$-function. Define $L:C(X)\to C(X)$ by 
$$Lf(x)=\sum_{y\in T^{-1}x}f(y)g(y).$$
I.e. $L$ is the transfer operator of $\log g$. We call a fixed point of the adjoint $L^*$ a $g$-measure. Finally we define, for any $n\in \mathbb N$
$$\operatorname{var}_n(\log g):=\sup_{x,y\in X}\{|\log(x)-\log(y)|:x_i=y_i\forall 0\leq i\leq n\}.$$

Theorem 3.1 of [1] is the following statement:

> If $g$ so defined satisfies $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \operatorname{var}_n(\log g)<\infty$, then there exists a unique $g$-measure $\mu$, and $L^n f\to \mu(f)$ uniformly for each $f\in C(X)$.

There are many ingredients in Walter's proof (which he adapted from Keane), but there is one particular portion I do not grasp:

He first shows that, for any fixed $f\in C(X)$, $\{L^nf\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is an equicontinuous subset of $C(X)$, which is also uniformly bounded by $\|f\|$. Thus Arzela-Ascoli guarantees the existence of a $\tilde f\in C(X)$ and subsequence $(n_k)$ such that $L^{n_k}f\to \tilde f$ in norm. Furthermore using the definition of $L$ and a simple convergence argument he shows
$$\min_X(f)\leq\min_X(Lf)\leq\cdots\leq \min_X(\tilde f)\leq \max_X(\tilde f)\leq\cdots\leq \max_X(Lf)\leq \max_X (f).$$

From this we can deduce that $\min_X(\tilde f)=\min_X(L^n\tilde f)$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$. Thus for any $x\in X$ such that $L^n\tilde f(x)=\min_X(L^n\tilde f)$, we can deduce that there must exist a $x_n\in T^{-n}x$ such that $\tilde f(x_n)=\min_X(\tilde f)$. So far, so good.

However, Walters now just states that mixing guarantees that every cylinder set contains a point on which $\tilde f$ obtains its minimum. I am having trouble rigorously proving this statement. Recall that a cylinder set is of the form $C=\{(x_i)\in X:x_j=a_0,\dots, x_{n+j}=a_n\}$, i.e. it is any set where some finite sequence of coordinates of the elements are fixed. Topological mixing here means that for any non-empty, open $U, V\subset X$ there exists a $N\in\mathbb N$ such  that $T^{-n}U\cap V\neq \emptyset$ for all $n\geq N$.

I believe the idea Walters has is to form some sequence of dense open sets $U_n$, such that the intersection contains only these minimization points, and use the Baire Category Theorem. However, it seems to me that we do not yet know enough to form these sets. For any $n\in\mathbb N$ we can find a finite set $\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}$ such that $x_i\in T^{-1}x_{i+1}$, and $L^i\tilde f(x_i)$ attains the minimum of $\tilde f$. What we need, for a simple proof at least, is that for any $x$ on which $\tilde f$ attains its minimum we have that $T^{-1}x$ contains points on which $\tilde f$ attains its minimum. So, in short:

> How exactly does Walters conclude from mixing that every cylinder set contains a point on which $\tilde f$ attains its minimum?

[1] *Walters, Peter*, [**Ruelles’s operator theorem and g-measures**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1997113), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 214, 375-387 (1975). [ZBL0331.28013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0331.28013).

Comment: @mathworker21 I am not sure how much more self-contained I can make it. The proof makes essential use of $L$ being a transfer operator and $T$ being topologically mixing. We only care about this specific $\tilde f \in C(X)$ arising from the transfer operator. Not sure how considering an arbitrary continuous function would help

Comment: Ok, I just read your post in full now. It is well-written. I think one important thing to note is that *every* $x_n \in T^{-n} x$ satisfies $\tilde{f}(x_n) = \min_X(\tilde{f})$; this is because $g$ is strictly positive. It now seems to me like the fact that every cylinder set contains a point on which $\tilde{f}$ attains its minimum follows just because $n$ is arbitrary, and topological mixing is actually unnecessary. Indeed, if we want the cylinder set $\{(y_j)_j : y_0 = a_0, \dots, y_m = a_m\}$, then just take $n > m$, $x$ such that $L^n\tilde{f}(x) = \min_X(L^n\tilde{f})$, and then

Comment: $y \in T^{-n} x$ with $y_0 = a_0, \dots, y_m = a_m$ (which we can do since $n > m$). Am I missing something?

Comment: @mathworker21 The problem is that all we know is there exists at least one $y\in T^{-n} x$ such that $\tilde f( y)$ is the minimum, but we cannot (at least as far as I see) guarantee what the first coordinates of $y$ are just from the mentioned arguments.

Comment: did you read what I wrote? I explicitly said that *every* $y \in T^{-n} x$ is such that $\tilde{f}(y)$ is the minimum.

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes actually. I agree if $g$ is strictly positive that's enough to guarantee all $y$ satisfy the condition. That does make it very trivial though, and I am now curious as to why Walter mentions mixing at all?

Comment: you're welcome. I don't know why you're saying "if"; you said $g$ is strictly positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g$ is strictly positive, if $x$ is such that $L^n\tilde{f}(x) = \min_X(L^n\tilde{f})$, then *all* $y \in T^{-n}x$ satisfy $\tilde{f}(y) = \min_X(\tilde{f})$. Now, as noted in the paper you reference, topological mixing implies $\cup_{n=0}^\infty T^{-n}x$ is dense in $X$, so, given any cylinder set $C$, there is some $n$ with $T^{-n}x \cap C \not = \emptyset$.

.

Topological mixing is an important hypothesis. For example, suppose $X$ is the set of all $(x_j)_{j=1}^\infty \in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ such that there is no $j$ with $x_j = 1, x_{j+1} = 0$. Suppose that $L^n\tilde{f}(x) = \min_X(L^n \tilde{f})$ for $x = (0,0,0,\dots)$. If $C = \{(y_1,y_2,\dots) : y_1 = 1\}$, then there is no $n$ with $T^{-n}x \cap C \not = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was convinced that mixing was essential, so blinded myself to simpler possibilities. Do you perhaps have any idea as to why Walters thought to involve mixing at all?

Comment: I mean, I don't, since it's so trivial.

Comment: I guess I'll ask a question on Overflow then, maybe there is another reason why it's important.

Comment: @K.Power I mean, I can look through the rest of the proof if you want. I'm capable of finding that other reason if there is one.

Comment: If you'd be interested that would be great, but even if you don't I'll award the bounty when the time arrives.

Comment: @K.Power oh wait. we're dealing with subshifts of finite type

Comment: You use mixing in the "It trivially follows"... That part is false is the system is not mixing.

Comment: @K.Power see the updated answer. everything is correct now. sorry for my previous answer. i forgot we were in the context of subshifts of finite type.

Comment: Yes thank you. I see realise my mistake was in misinterpreting his implied quantifiers. Thank you for pointing it out, and for the nice counterexample. Will award the bounty when I'm able to